# What happened to issubclass?

Tags: python, types, built-in

Before modifying the c.py file, why do two different results appear? The results show that the two classes are different. What happened to issubclass? Here I use globals() to modify the global variables. Is there a better way?

```
"""
├─myapp
|  ├─mypackge 
|      ├─init.py
|      ├─a.py
│      ├─b.py
|      ├─c.py
"""

#a.py
class A:
    pass

#b.py
from mypackge.a import A
class B(A):
    pass
    
#c.py
from a import A as A1
from mypackge.a import A as A2 
from b import B

print(A1, A2) # output: <class 'a.A'> <class 'mypackage.a.A'>
print(issubclass(B, A1)) # output: False
print(issubclass(B, A2)) # output: True


# Next, I try to modify the c.py file using globals()
from a import A as A1
from mypackage.a import A as A2
from b import B

from pprint import pprint

pprint(globals())
print('-' * 50)
globals()['A1'] = A2
pprint(globals())
print(issubclass(B, A1))
print(issubclass(B, A2))
# ouput:
"""
{'A1': <class 'a.A'>,
 'A2': <class 'mypackage.a.A'>,
 'B': <class 'b.B'>,
 ... 
--------------------------------------------------
{'A1': <class 'mypackage.a.A'>,
 'A2': <class 'mypackage.a.A'>,
 'B': <class 'b.B'>,
 ...
True
True
"""
```